# Nginx 301 when accessing a proxied domain locally

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, http-status-code-301

I have a Nginx running as a reverse proxy for a domain, let's call it "testdomain.com", the proxy itself is working, and I can access this website from almost anywhere I want, except locally.

To clarify it better, here's my architecture:

I have a ESXi server which has a pfsense VM, the pfsense VM port forwards all requests destined to port 80 to the port 80 of another VM. That VM has a docker container which is running nginx, so it sends to port 80 of the container, and then it proxy pass the HTTP request to another external server where tha application (WordPress) is hosted. As I said it earlier, it works fine, however, if execute a curl locally (i.e wihitn my first my first VM or nginx container) to my address it returns the following:

```
curl testdomain.com
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

It seems that Nginx can't find the vhost, here's how my .conf for the website looks:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        modsecurity on;
        modsecurity_rules_file /etc/nginx/modsec/main.conf;
        server_name testdomain.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;


    location / {
                add_header Cache-Control public;
                add_header Pragma public;
                add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
                expires 60M;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass http://myexternalserver.com:80;
    }
}

server {

        modsecurity on;
        modsecurity_rules_file /etc/nginx/modsec/main.conf;
        listen 443 ssl http2;
        server_name testdomain.com;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx-selfsigned.key;

        # 
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

        # 
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;
        # 
        ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

        # 
        add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" always;

        #
        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:40m;
        ssl_session_timeout 4h;
        ssl_session_tickets on;

        location / {
                add_header Cache-Control public;
                add_header Pragma public;
                add_header Vary Accept-Encoding;
                expires 60M;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_pass https://myexternalserver.com:443;
        }
}
```

I apologize if I miss any relevant info.

Thank you!

Comment: try `curl -L testdomain.com`

Comment: Oh thank you very much, I think i got it, unfortunately curl -L does not work because of SSL issues, however we can bypass that with -k. accordingly with the results, it seems it got stucked in pfsense, since it was detected as a possible attack

Comment: <a href="index.php?logout">Potential DNS Rebind attack detected, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_rebinding<br />Try accessing the router by IP address instead of by hostname.</a>